# How to see , how much a file is downloaded while using qtwebengine of pyqt5 in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

**My Whole Source code is here.**
tried something like  **downloaded()** method but i don't think it's proper way of doing such.
Please help in using *

1. DownloadInProgress
2. downloadProgress

   etc.
   I'm failed in making a system of file download system with download progress bar.

   ```
   from PyQt5.QtCore import *
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
   from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
   import sys
   class Example(QWidget):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.resize(640, 320)
           self.setWindowTitle('PyQt-5 WebEngine')
   ****
   ```

---

---

```
        self.web_view = QWebEngineView()
        self.web_view.loadProgress.connect(self.webLoading)
        self.web_view.loadFinished.connect(self.webloadFinished)
        self.web_view.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(self.on_downloadRequested)
        ****
```

---

---

````
    def webLoading(self, event):
        self.progress.show()
        self.progress.setValue(event)
        
    @pyqtSlot("QWebEngineDownloadItem*")
    def downloaded(self, rec,total):
        print('Downloaded:',(rec/1024)/1024,'/',(total/1024)/1024,' MB')
    
    def downloadfinished(self,filename):
        print(filename+' Downloaded!')
            
    @pyqtSlot("QWebEngineDownloadItem*")
    def on_downloadRequested(self, download):

        old_path = download.url().path()  # download.path()
        suffix = QFileInfo(old_path).suffix()
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, "Save File", old_path, "*." + suffix
        )
        if path:
            download.setPath(path)
            download.accept()
        try:
##            download.DownloadInProgress.connect(self.downloaded)
            download.finished.connect(lambda:self.downloadfinished(path.rsplit('/')[-1]))
        except Exception as e:print(e)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = Example()
    app.show()
    application.exec()```
````

Comment: `DownloadInProgress` is a [`DownloadState`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginedownloaditem.html#DownloadState-enum), not a signal. Use [`downloadProgress`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginedownloaditem.html#downloadProgress).

Comment: You should always check the formatting of your code before submitting your question.